# R : How to use 'for' loop to create variables using dplyr's mutate?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I want to use dplyr's 'mutate' to create variables in a loop. I have 4 variables a) yield_corn_total, b) yield_soybeans_total, c) yield_wheat_total, d) yield_sorghum_total. I want to create 4 other variables which are log of these 4 existing variables and they should be named a) log_yield_corn_total, b) log_yield_soybeans_total, c) log_yield_wheat_total, d) log_yield_sorghum_total

When I run the following code :

```
 crops <- c( "corn", "soybeans", "wheat", "sorghum")
    data <- data %>% 
      for (i in crops){ 
      mutate(sym(paste0("log_yield_",i,"_total")) := log(paste0("yield_",i,"_total")))
    }
```

I get the following error :

```
Error in for (. in i) crops : 
  4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `for` loops, use `across()`. This is untested as you haven't provided sample data, but it should work--if not, please provide some sample data for debugging, e.g. `dput(data[1:4, ])`

```
crops <- c( "corn", "soybeans", "wheat", "sorghum")
cols = paste("yield", crops, "total", sep = "_")
data %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(cols), log, .names = "log_{.col}"))
```

Comment: Nice!. Do you need `all_of()` here? I thought `mutate(across(cols, log, .names="log_{.col}"))` would do it?

Comment: @langtang as long as there's not a column called "`cols`" in the data. Probably fine in most cases, but I'd say using `all_of()` here is better practice in general.

Comment: Chiming in to agree that you had it right the first time and should be using `all_of()` as a matter of best practice - not using it when passing an external vector of column names triggers the once-per-session note and direction to visit https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html. This will become a warning and then an error in future versions according to the link.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already into the tidyverse `{dplyr}`, you could also leverage one of the "tidy" principles: one column per variable. This means [reshaping your data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html?q=pivot_longer#longer) table from wide (one column per crop type x yield) to long (one column for crop type, one for yield). This makes a lot of manipulations easier. Only after all calculations are done, the table might be reverted to wide format for presentational purposes.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(
    farm = 'Bonanza',
    yield_corn_total = 34,
    yield_soybeans_total = 87,
    yield_wheat_total = 34,
    yield_sorghum_total = 12
)

df %>%
    ## from wide to long:
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with('yield'),
        names_to = 'crop', 
        values_to = 'total_yield'
    ) %>%
    ## do some manipulations
    mutate(crop = crop %>%
               ## strip all except the actual crop name:
               gsub('yield_','',.) %>% gsub('_total','',.),
           log_yield = log(total_yield)
           ) %>%
    ## further manipulations like filtering, summarising
    ## e.g. filter (log_yield > 2, farm == 'Ponderosa')
    ## ... 
    ## if need be, make it a 'wide' table again:
    pivot_wider(
        values_from = ends_with('yield'),
        names_from = crop
    )
```